# Full Text Indexing After Modifying a Record

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have an application uses viewpanels to display data.  One viewpanel displays unprocessed records and the other displays processed records.  The user chooses an unprocessed record (using the show values in this column as links option), and is directed to a page where they input information.  Then then click on button that updates the documents using doc.replaceItemValue statements in javascript.  The user is then directed back to the viewpanel that displays the unprocessed records.  In order to have the just processed record not show up in the unprocessed records I have to reindex the database.  I am using database.updateFTIndex(false) to accomplish this.
Is there a better way to accomplish this?  If two are more users are submitting records, will their individual indexes step on each other?
I never had to worry about this when using mysql.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Did you check the refresh setting on the underlying view that the viewpanel is displaying? It's the "beanie hat" tab (5th tab). If you have it set to "Auto, after first use" then updating a document and doing a partial refresh on the viewpanel should reflect the change. Full text index has nothing to do with view indexes, they are separate types of indexes.

Comment: The refresh setting on the underlying view that the viewpanel is displaying is/was set to "Auto, after first use".  However, I am not just using one xpage.  1st page is the viewpanel and the user selects the record to update.  A new page is loaded to edit the record.  Once the edits are submitted using javascript executed via the onclick event of the button, the user is redirected to the 1st page via an Open Page simple action that follows the Execute Script simple action .  So, I guess technically it is a full page reload and the contents of the viewpanel were not getting updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used that technique for a while in production and not been notified of any issues. Updating an index via the Database Properties or a View gives the message that it has been queued for update on the server, but I'm not sure if the same happens with the programmatic call. It may well do.

In my scenario, I'm consolidating a lot of data into individual documents, so although intensive use periodically, it's not a huge number of documents being updated at any one time.

I'm also running the update to the index via `sessionAsSigner`, I had assumed that would be needed for authority purposes.

Comment: Good to know.  I think I will be safe.  I will not have a huge number of documents being updated at any one time  - just the one.  Also, I am pretty sure that the usage will not be that intense.  I will need to look into the authority issue.  So, far testing with users has not been a problem even though I am not using sessionAsSigner.